# Make reference to variable

Tags: python, reference, python-2.7

In C++ you can do the following:

```
int x = 10;
int &y = x;
y = 11;
cout << x << endl; // will print 11
```

How can I do something similar in python?  Trying to make `self.session` a reference to `self.request.session`:

```
self.session = self.request.session
```

Comment: In **C++** you can do the following...

Comment: Yes, it does what you want it to.

Comment: @LevLevitsky It doesn't, depending on what he wants. If he wants to avoid copies, yeah. If he wants `self.session = ...` to affect `self.request.session`, **no**.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm guessing you want self.session to be updated as well whenever self.request.session is assigned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will make both `self.session` and `self.request.session` refer to the same object:

```
self.session = self.request.session
```

If you make a change to `session` via either of the two references, you'll be able to observe the change through both:

```
 self.session.set_foo(42)
 self.request.session.get_foo() # returns 42
```

If you, on the other hand, *rebind* either reference by making it point someplace else, that'll break the link:

```
 self.session = another_session
```

Finally, it is important to note that certain Python types are immutable. This includes integers, strings and tuples. While you can have multiple references to an immutable object, the immutability prevents you from making any changes to that object.

This is relevant in light of your C++ example. If you wanted to have a shared reference to an `int`, and be able to modify that `int`, you'd have to wrap the `int` inside a mutable object, and share references to that mutable object instead.

Comment: As I already told others in the question comments, this is **not** the same as . `self.session =` will have no effect on `self.request.session`, whereas in the C++ code, `y = ...` affects `x`. -1

Comment: Immutability has absolutely no relevance here.

Comment: +1 Now that's correct. In fact, it may be the shortest correct explanation of this topic I've ever read.

Comment: what if I do something like `self.session['test'] = 123`.  Will self.request.session now have the key 'test' pointing to the value 123?

Comment: ok.  in my case i am referencing self.session to self.request.session to save myself some typing :P  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In python, everything is a reference to an object.  The assignment operator *creates* a new reference to the object referenced on the right hand side.

Consider:

```
a = [1,2]
b = a
b.append(3)
print a  #prints [1, 2, 3]
```

Your example code does what you want -- creates a new reference to the `self.request.session` object.  Be careful though.  remember that doing another assignemt to the name `self.request` will now cause `self.request` to reference a *different* object.

Comment: One never binds a reference to an object. One binds references to names (among a few other things).

Comment: @delnan -- What's the distinction?

Comment: Neither object knows a thing about `b` and is not, in any way, affected by the assignment to `b`. Only the name is changed to refer to another object. It simply doesn't enter the picture.

Comment: You can't say that you bind a *name* either though.  what about `a[0] = 'foo'`.  You're not binding a *name*.  You're creating a new reference to the object and putting it somewhere.  (and the object does need to know something about the references in Cpython because of the garbage collector).

Comment: Also (yeah, I'm copypasting this): As I already told others in the question comments, this is **not** the same as references in C++. `self.session =` will have no effect on `self.request.session`, whereas in the C++ code, `y = ...` affects `x`. -1

Comment: That's why I wrote "names (among a few other things)". Yes, you're creating a new reference to the object referenced by what's on the right hand side. But you're not binding that reference to an(other) *object*. That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @delnan -- What if I use the term `creates` instead of `binds`.  It *creates* a new reference to the object on the RHS.  I can honestly never seem to come up with a way to say this which pleases everybody ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's good, and yes, it's tricky to phrase this well :) By the way, I must admit I misread your post to say "binds a new reference to the object referenced on the **left** hand side", though that doesn't invalidate my main point.